# How can I achieve this using jackson jsonNode and get the desired output

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson

Json response

```
{
    "searchResults": {
        "@xmlns": {
            "dvi": "http://localhsot.com/ns/1.0",
            "$": "http://localhsot.com/ns/1.0",
            "a": "http://alternate.localhsot.com/ns/1.0"
        },
        "@totalCount": "2",
        "file": [
            {
                "link": [
                    {
                        "@rel": "file",
                        "$": "file.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content",
                        "$": "content.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "repository",
                        "$": "repository.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "320",
                        "@a:height": "320",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "64",
                        "@a:height": "64",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "24",
                        "@a:height": "24",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "128",
                        "@a:height": "128",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    }
                ],
                "name": {
                    "$": "gullfoss.jpg"
                },
                "parentPath": {
                    "$": "/"
                },
                "size": {
                    "$": "91345"
                },
                "versionCreated": {
                    "$": "2017-01-13T16:38:20.059Z"
                },
                "systemAttribute": [
                    {
                        "@name": "Geo-Latitude",
                        "$": "47.6065"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Geo-Longitude",
                        "$": "22.99514"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Height",
                        "$": "579"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Mime-Type",
                        "$": "image/jpeg"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Timeline-Date",
                        "$": "-0091-03-27T04:26:40.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Width",
                        "$": "680"
                    }
                ],
                "attributesChanged": {
                    "$": "false"
                },
                "deleted": {
                    "$": "false"
                },
                "repository": {
                    "$": "VZMOBILE_13psb6j"
                },
                "checksum": {
                    "$": "5d828c1d94b2569ff1bf60a9ebe9cd2de8ae8e6a9ad7d77d678c1766c78957c5"
                },
                "extension": {
                    "$": "jpg"
                },
                "fileAttribute": [
                    {
                        "@name": "ContentPermissions",
                        "$": "SHARE"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Width",
                        "$": "680"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "CI_COMPLETE",
                        "$": "true"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "DRM_PROTECTED",
                        "$": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Height",
                        "$": "579"
                    }
                ],
                "contentToken": {
                    "$": "AHYLsb1sK9iy1Rn3yS4mQiM5pFL--AyTjY3i5G-zzdOm68QzB_GILrt1pXgfdEkUcPZZ5tUpn1Ih3j9wyfywIVY~"
                },
                "contentAccessible": {
                    "$": "true"
                },
                "contentChanged": {
                    "$": "false"
                }
            },
            {
                "link": [
                    {
                        "@rel": "file",
                        "$": "file.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content",
                        "$": "content.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "repository",
                        "$": "repository.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "320",
                        "@a:height": "320",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "64",
                        "@a:height": "64",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "24",
                        "@a:height": "24",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    },
                    {
                        "@rel": "content.alternate",
                        "@a:width": "128",
                        "@a:height": "128",
                        "@a:imageFormat": "jpeg",
                        "@a:mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                        "@a:size": "-1",
                        "$": "some.url"
                    }
                ],
                "name": {
                    "$": "gullfoss.jpg"
                },
                "parentPath": {
                    "$": "/Folder"
                },
                "size": {
                    "$": "91345"
                },
                "versionCreated": {
                    "$": "2017-01-13T16:38:59.728Z"
                },
                "systemAttribute": [
                    {
                        "@name": "Geo-Latitude",
                        "$": "47.6065"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Geo-Longitude",
                        "$": "22.99514"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Height",
                        "$": "579"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Mime-Type",
                        "$": "image/jpeg"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Timeline-Date",
                        "$": "-0091-03-27T04:26:40.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Width",
                        "$": "680"
                    }
                ],
                "attributesChanged": {
                    "$": "false"
                },
                "deleted": {
                    "$": "false"
                },
                "repository": {
                    "$": "VZMOBILE_13psb6j"
                },
                "checksum": {
                    "$": "5d828c1d94b2569ff1bf60a9ebe9cd2de8ae8e6a9ad7d77d678c1766c78957c5"
                },
                "extension": {
                    "$": "jpg"
                },
                "fileAttribute": [
                    {
                        "@name": "ContentPermissions",
                        "$": "SHARE"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Width",
                        "$": "680"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "CI_COMPLETE",
                        "$": "true"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "DRM_PROTECTED",
                        "$": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "@name": "Height",
                        "$": "579"
                    }
                ],
                "contentToken": {
                    "$": "AHYLsb1sK9iy1Rn3yS4mQiM5pFL--AyTjY3i5G-zzdOm68QzB_GILrt1pXgfdEkUcPZZ5tUpn1Ih3j9wyfywIVY~"
                },
                "contentAccessible": {
                    "$": "true"
                },
                "contentChanged": {
                    "$": "false"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to check two condition by travesing this json response i.e., First get the @totalCount from the above json string

second condition, loop through each file node and see

if(myrepoName.equals(json response repository name)
 then get the content url for repository from link node. which is this

```
{
    "@rel": "content",
    "$": "content.url"  <---
}
```

My Code:

```
try {
    JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response.prettyPrint());
    int totalCount = jsonNode.at("/searchResults/@totalCount").asInt();
    logger.info("Search returned " + totalCount + " results");
    if(totalCount > 0) {
        JsonNode filesNode = jsonNode.at("/searchResults/file");
        logger.info("Result: " + filesNode);
        if(filesNode.isObject()) {
            Iterator<JsonNode> filesIterator = filesNode.elements();
            while (filesIterator.hasNext())
            {
                // what i'm trying to get here is this
                JsonNode fileNode = filesIterator.next();
                Object name = fileNode.at("/$").asText();
                if (repoName.equals(name)) {
                    logger.info("Got it");
                    //get the content URL from link node
                    //missing code 
                    logger.info("Returning " + contentURL + " for repo " + repoName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the JSON node `filesNode` is not a JSON object. As you can find in your example, this node has structure `"file": [ ... ]`, which is a JSON array. So you need to change the if-statement, if the files node is an array, then continue:

```
// wrong
if (filesNode.isObject()) {
    ...
}

// correct
if (filesNode.isArray()) {
    ...
}
```

Secondly, you need to exact the JSON node `repository` inside the JSON object `file` to check if the name of the repo is correct:

```
//
// },
// "repository": {
//     "$": "VZMOBILE_13psb6j"
// },
//
String repoName = fileNode.at("/repository/$").asText();
if (repoName.equals(targetRepoName)) {
```

Thirdly, you need to exact the JSON node `link` inside the JSON object `file` to find the content link.

```
for (JsonNode linkNode : linksNode) {
    if ("content".equals(linkNode.get("@rel").asText())) {
        return linkNode.get("$").asText();
    }
}
```

Here's the entire code.

```
// ...
JsonNode filesNode = jsonNode.at("/searchResults/file");
if (filesNode.isArray()) {

  for (JsonNode fileNode : filesNode) {
    String repoName = fileNode.at("/repository/$").asText();
    if (repoName.equals(targetRepoName)) {

      for (JsonNode linkNode : fileNode.at("/link")) {
        if ("content".equals(linkNode.get("@rel").asText())) {
          contentURL = linkNode.get("$").asText();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mincong. You've just made my day.

Comment: @SyedShareefAhmed it's my pleasure to help you. Happy coding and have a nice day!